# Right way to transform the uibutton

Tags: objective-c, rotation, cgaffinetransform

When I made the transfrom UIButton background image showed ragged side

[image]

My code is here:

```
int r = arc4random() % 20 - 10;
avatarImgBtn.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(r));
titleImgBtn.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(r));
title.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(r));

avatarImgBtn.layer.borderWidth = 3;
avatarImgBtn.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
avatarImgBtn.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
```

How can I do the right. Please help me. Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Two simple ways to do antialiasing:

1. add a transparent 1px boarder for the button if the image is strictly rectangle.
   `avatarImgBtn.layer.borderWidth = 1;`

   `avatarImgBtn.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;`
2. Edit the image and add 1px of transparent pixels around it.

Comment: thanks for your answer. and there need to be added one line of code. i edited.